# external login google auth

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I tried using both default templates - single page app and web api to get my access token from google. Both apps throw an error has occured.

single page app -
I sign in with google
it calls externallogincallback method and crashes.

api -
I get api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
It calls GetExternalLogin()
I sign into google
It calls GetExternalLogin() and crashes.

The crashes don't show anything in the try catch - probably because I am running it live and debugging through attached processed.

Google developer console says login succeed. My cookie shows an asp.net external cookie is there.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I needed to enable ssl in localhost and both templates started working.